# "Route not admitted by a router" on Openshift Online v3

Tags: openshift

I have an application deployed on Openshift Online v3 starter plan which (used to) run well until yesterday. Yesterday I had to publish a new version of my application. Apparently, the platform encountered some problems redeploying it, I had to cancel some processes which seemed locked or continually restarting. 
Finally I managed to have my pod running with the new version, the logs look fine.

The issue now is that my app is no longer exposed. When hitting the URL which was assigned to me, I got the infamous "not available" OO page:

```
Application is not available

The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.

Possible reasons you are seeing this page:

    The host doesn't exist. Make sure the hostname was typed correctly and that a route matching this hostname exists.
    The host exists, but doesn't have a matching path. Check if the URL path was typed correctly and that the route was created using the desired path.
    Route and path matches, but all pods are down. Make sure that the resources exposed by this route (pods, services, deployment configs, etc) have at least one pod running.
```

I checked these 3 suggestions, and got sure that my host existed, that the path was correct, and that my pods where up. So, not understanding what the real issue was, I dropped the existing route and created a new one.

It's been 2 hours now, and the route UI keeps displaying this message:

```
The route is not accepting traffic yet because it has not been admitted by a router.
```

My understanding is  that the router which should admit my route is not part of my project, it is managed by Openshift Online, am I right ?

So what could I do now to unlock my new route ?

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Starter clusters are experience some issues. You can track status at https://status.starter.openshift.com/

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It's been nearly 2 weeks though since the status notification on starter-ca-central...

Comment: The problems have been coming and going at different times so rather than keeping pulling it down each time it abates, it has been left up as they continue to understand the root cause and test fixes.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. Can you point me to a blog / mailing list where I could follow the progress of the team about this issue ? Other than the status page of Openshift, I mean

Comment: Subscribing to changes to the status page is the only public place I know that information is being made available.

Comment: West coast still down also :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There it is  ! My application is reachable again at last : It took 2 days for the router to setup my route. No action required from my part.
But the starter platform is still experiencing difficulties, so I will avoid any redeployment until the status turns green again.

Comment: I am also having this issue right now. And status is green :) I am on starter us east 1... Do you still had this issue afterwards?

Comment: No I did not. However, I've noticed that a redeployment that I have not requested had been attempted on my pods. So, strange things are still happening...

Comment: I enabled the Pro plan. There the route is created instantly. After 1 second it was allready available! However, I have other issues creating a pod. Logged a case, but no answer. I think we need to be patient in general with this V3 =) =)

Comment: I have also created an app but the api route saying the application is not available. Waiting for around 6hours. Still no luck. Did you make any changes after exposing the app?

Comment: No change, but I dropped and recreated the route with the same parameters several times. Has your route been created yet ?